# How to get pathname in NextJS /_document.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get the current pathname in /page/_document.js file. I'm using a class, and my objective is to make a conditional with that value.

Here's my code (is basically the example in NextJS' page)

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it by `ctx.req.url` or `ctx.asPath` but `getInitialProps` only executed at first time you access to app

> Note: 's getInitialProps function is not called during client-side transitions, nor when a page is automatically statically optimized.
>
> Note: Make sure to check if ctx.req / ctx.res are defined in
>   getInitialProps. These variables will be undefined when a page is
>   being statically exported for next export or automatic static
>   optimization.

[Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/old#custom-document)

Comment: what if you're using a functional component?